# Getting cron job to execute script on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) XAMPP

Tags: cron, xampp

Been messing around with XAMPP Cron Jobs for awhile and can't seem to get these to work right. This is being run on my personal computer for Mac OSX Yosemite. Using the terminal to make this work. The script is a PHP file. I put the default application to open up in a browser. It runs the cron job but it opens it up as if it is a text file and not as if it is a php script.

I did test this individually script separate from the cron and it works fine. Just for testing purposes I have it just writing to basic txt file. The paths are the default that pretty much comes with XAMPP.

Example of cron job in terminal

1 * * * * /usr/bin/open /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest of my path/write.php

The cron job does pull up the script in the default browser but is read like a text file.

So in the URL bar it starts off with file:// and than the cron job command path listed in the example.

Two questions:

## 1 Is there a way to make this execute the same way if I visited the webpage?

## 2 Is there a way to make this run in the background?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I had no troubles finding a way to run a URL via cron by [Googling "cron run url"](https://www.google.com.au/#q=cron+run+url):  `wget http://localhost/write.php` etc. If you want it to run without wget, then you can also run it via php directly. Again, a quick [Google: "cron run php"](https://www.google.com.au/#q=cron+run+php).

Comment: Christian Varga, thanks. That pretty much did it after adding curl right before the link. I was use to doing cron jobs on a remote shared server where they wanted the full file path so I thought it would need the file path. This also seemed to make it work in the background so you solved both of my questions. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome, glad it's working for you